# Publishing checkins using facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/profile-id/checkins?access_token=access_token&message="the office"

I am using the above graph api,to publish a checkin on my feed,I tried this on my browser,
I am getting empty array as response,I also used access_token from graph api explorer which is permitted for (publish-checkins).

I am getting the response like below

```
     {
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: To publish a checkin, you must provide a `place_id` to checkin to. Check the Checkins Create section here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: I just want to do some fake checkin like  (-at the office),how to get place id and what is the use of using co-ordinates parameter,if I just want to do fake checkin

Comment: Check the answer I am posting. This is how I do it using the FB SDK V 2x. Haven't moved to V 3.x yet. You will have to adapt my code to use with the new SDK (perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

```
final JSONObject jsonobj;

try {

    jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    jsonobj.put("latitude", fetLatitude);
    jsonobj.put("longitude", fetLongitude);

    final String message;
    final String name = fetPlaceName;
    final String placeID = fetPlaceID;

    if (edittxtMessageBox != null){
        message = edittxtMessageBox.getText().toString();
    } else {
        message = "I am at: " + fetPlaceName  + " using MyAppName";
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.check_in_title)
        .setMessage(String.format(this.getString(R.string.check_in_at), name))
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.checkin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("place", placeID);
                params.putString("message", message);
                params.putString("coordinates", jsonobj.toString());
                Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/checkins", params, "POST",
                        new placesCheckInListener(), null);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @user1891910: In my app, when the user selects the `Checkin` option, he is presented with a list of places to choose from. When selected, the `place_id` and the `co-ordinates` are sent via an `Intent` to the activity where I use the code posted above. You will need to do something on those lines. If you want to do _fake checkins_, you can use a static `place_id` and `co-oridinates`.

Comment: I have to do checkin by using my own names like "the office","the gym",.... like this.So what is this placeid's and how to create these,and why to use coordinates parameter

Comment: You can only checkin to places which are available on Facebook. You will need to create your own places if they aren't already available. And why to use `co-ordinates`? Because they are needed by the FB API to place a checkin.

Comment: so,how to create own checkin places by using graph api

Comment: I have six fake checkin images,when I click on those it should move to another where I do checkin.For these six icons,how can I create place_ids and what co-ordinates I need to use.Does these co-ordinates make any difference.

Comment: @user1891910: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. As to how you get the `place_id` and `co-ordinates`, you will get them from the Facebook API. But you will need to know the `place_id` to get the `co-ordinates`. I am not sure how you can create the places you need. I never had to create one. I believe the code above should answer your question on how to post. The other questions are really usage and I have no clue about creating places, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21311/discussion-between-user1891910-and-siddharth-lele)